# Check if a directory that meets a certain criteria exists in bash

Tags: bash, shell, directory

I am trying to get bash to check if a directory exists, but only if it meets a certain criteria.

For instance, I want to check if a directory that starts with `pkg_`, with any other characters following, exists.

So in the event a folder named `pkg_1.0` or `pkg_2.0` exists, bash would still catch it.

At the moment the code looks something like this:

```
if [ -d "~/pkg_*" ];
```

but every time this is run, it returns false regardless of the existence of any directory begging with `pkg_`

At the same time, using `cd ~/pkg_*` works just fine, and I am able to `cd` into that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for path in ~/pkg_*/
do
    [do what you want if at least one such directory exists]
    break
done
```

Explanation:

- Setting `nullglob` ensures that `~/pkg_*/` resolves to the empty string if no such directory exists, meaning that we don't enter the loop.
- The **trailing slash** ensures that we only match directories, not ordinary files.
- To [expand tilde and asterisk](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) the way you want these characters need to be **unquoted.** If [quoted](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) these match *literal* tilde and asterisk characters in filenames, which is possible but very unusual.
- **`break` stops going through the loop,** so the conditional is only run once.

Example session:

```
$ cd
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for path in ~/pkg_*/
> do
>     echo 'Found one!'
>     break
> done
$ mkdir 'pkg_a'
$ for path in ~/pkg_*/
> do
>     echo 'Found one!'
>     break
> done
Found one!
$ mkdir 'pkg_b with spaces'
$ for path in ~/pkg_*/
> do
>     echo 'Found one!'
>     break
> done
Found one!
```

Answer (score 0):

I really depends on where you need to look for the directories. If you simply need to check whether there are `pkg_...` named directories within a single directory, then you can use a `for` loop, looping over the directories within a given directory as IObO indicates in his answer.

If however you need to search all subdirectories under a given directory for directories named `pkg_...`, then using `find` provides a convenient option. In bash, you can use *process substitution* to feed directory names matching your criteria to a `while` loop, e.g.

```
while read -r pkgdir; do
    ## do what you need with "$pkgdir"
done < <(find /path -type d -name "pkg_*")
```

(**note:** the space between `< <` is required)

The `find` command will locate all directories `-type d` below `/path` where the name matches the glob `"pkg_*"`. These will be read by the `while` loop into the variable `pkgdir`. You can then process the directory in `"$pkgdir"` in any way required.

You can also use the `-exec` option to find to execute any single command required or to call another script on each directory. You can also pipe the results to `xargs` and accomplish the same thing (suggest using `-print0` in `find` to output nul-terminated directory names and the `-0` option for `xargs` to indicate the same)

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Well, for one, `bash: read: '/home/cabox/': not a valid identifier` becomes an issue (this is for codeanywhere's Ubuntu bash), and for second I only need to know that the `pkg_*` exists _only in the directory specified_. the `find` function is looking in all subdirectories, causing issues with other folders that are unrelated but share a common `pkg_*`

Also, why is the `find` function following the `done`? I need to perform an action under the condition that a directory exists, so I don't know how to apply this to bash (I'm a beginner, and you'd know if you saw my github).

Comment: You can limit the depth `find` will search with the `-maxdepth 1` option (it must be the 1st option after `/path`). E.g. (`1` current `/path`, `2` for `/path/firstlevelsubs`, etc...)

Answer (score -1):

While not an elegant one-liner, you could try this:

```
filelist="$HOME/pkg_*"
for f in $filelist; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        action_if_true
    fi
done
```

However, this does have the side-effect of the action being performed more than once if you have multiple folders that match.

BTW, I used the environment variable $HOME in place of the tilde in the first line, as the tilde does not work.

I tested this and it appears to also work in a classic Bourne shell.

The bash experts out there may have a better answer.

Comment: @l0b0  I'm wondering what I missed.  This worked for me, other than what I outright mentioned about multiple matches.  Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Got it.  Spaces in a file or directory name caused it to fail.  But a simple addition of quotation marks around the "$f" corrects that.  Yes, then it still will match multiple folders.  That is good or bad depending on the exact intention.  The OP did not state whether multiple matches were acceptable or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

    fpath=`find ~/ -type d -name "pkg_*"` #which finds all folder start the name pkg_ in the path ~/
```

To perform separate action on each folder

```
for fnd in $fpath
do
    echo "$fnd"
done
```

To search in different path, replace `~/` as you wish

**Edit:** If the folder name contains white spaces use this

```
#!/bin/bash
  find . -type d | while read fpath; do echo $fpath; done
```

Comment: This won't work. If there are multiple matches it will run more than once, and it does bad things with spaces in filenames and `pkg_*` files deeper in the hierarchy.

Comment: @l0b0 did you tested ?

Comment: @l0b0 let me see the example what you trying to negate.

Comment: Yeah, I did test it. It ran twice when the `find` found two directories.

Comment: he didn't mention it will be only one directory in the path. My solution is generic ?